# Jest - test jquery fadeIn/fadeOut on specific elements

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, jestjs, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to write some test for a web app I'm building using jquery. I have some functions that fade some elements in an out, and would like to ensure this elements are being displayed as expected. I'm using jest for testing, but I have not figured out how to see if `$(...).fadeIn()` or `$(...).fadeOut()` are being called on specific elements. Here's an example

Let's say this is the dom

```html
<div>
 <span id="show-this" style="display: none"></span>
 <span id="hide-this"></span>
</div>
```

and this is the function I want to test

```js
function showAndHide() {
  $('#show-this').fadeIn();
  $('#hide-this').fadeOut();
}
```

currently the best test I've been able to do is spy on `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` and see if they're been called.

```js
it('should display the element', () => {
  const spyFadeIn = jest.spyOn($.fn, 'fadeIn');
  showAndHide();
  expect(spyFadeIn).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

it('should hide the element', () => {
  const spyFadeOut = jest.spyOn($.fn, 'fadeOut');
  showAndHide();
  expect(spyFadeOut).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

This is a good workaround, but in situations like this wont work, because the tests would pass if I fadeOut the `#show-this` and fadeIn the `#hide-this`, which I wish to cause a test fail. I tried checking the arguments of the function, since I know under the scene this functions receive the element as an argument, but jest is not seeing that. Any thoughts? I got stuck on my unit testing because of this.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is check for the style your element should have after fadeIn/fadeOut took effect. Usually fadeIn/fadeOut animate over time, but Jest can't handle that so we also need to disable jQuery effects before each test. The test suite would then look like this:

```js
describe('fadeIn/fadeOut tests', () => {
  beforeEach((): void => {
    $.fx.off = true; // Disable jQuery animations
  });

  afterEach((): void => {
    $.fx.off = false; // Enable jQuery animations
  });

  test('#show-this should fade in.', () => {
    showAndHide();
    expect($('#show-this').css('display')).toStrictEqual('block');
  });

  test('#hide-this should fade out.', () => {
    showAndHide();
    expect($('#hide-this').css('display')).toStrictEqual('none');
  });
});
```